# Mathematical operation with numpy array over ndaaray with different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have one numpy array with shape (12,) that looks like this:

```
array([0.111,0.222,0.333,0.444,0.555,0.666,0.777,0.888,0.999,0.100,0.011,0.12], dtype=float32)
```

In addition I have another array with 12 dimensions with shape (773,1231) :

```
>>>array([[[0.1448    , 0.1452    , 0.1452    , ..., 0.1589    ,
         0.1589    , 0.1589    ],
        [0.1448    , 0.1452    , 0.1452    , ..., 0.1589    ,
         0.1589    , 0.1589    ],
        [0.1454    , 0.1454    , 0.1454    , ..., 0.1582    ,
         0.1582    , 0.1582    ],
        ........
        ]]], dtype=float32)
```

The ndarray is an image with 12 bands, so baiscally wach pixel contains 12 values.
**I want to divide each pixel with the first array**, so for example if the first pixel is this:

```
>>>[0.721 , 0.124, 0.154 , 0.452  ,0.975 , 0.013 , 0.875 , 0.324 , 0.543 , 0.213 , 0.675 , 0.212 ]
```

**I want that the results will be the result calculation of this:**

```
>>>[0.721/0.111 , 0.124/0.222, 0.154/0.333, 0.452/0.444  ,0.975/0.555 , 0.013/0.666 , 0.875/0.777 , 0.324/0.888 , 0.543/0.999 , 0.2130.10 , 0.675/0.011 , 0.212/0.12 ]
```

So the result output should be basically to divide all the image in that line.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
little_array/image
```

but then I get the error

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (12,773,1231) (12,)

**My end goal: to divide each dimension by the correct number from the short array.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to broadcast the division like such:

```
divisors = np.array(...) # 12 elements
image = np.array(...) # shape (12,773,1231) image
image / divisors[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way Numpy broadcasting works is that the inner dimensions of the dividend and divisor must match, or be equal to one. You can interchange the dimensions by transposing the array. See the following:

```
image = np.random.randn(12, 773, 1231)
x = np.random.randn(12)
image.shape  # (12L, 773L, 1231L)
image.T.shape  # (1231L, 773L, 12L)
x.shape  # (12L,)
image / x  # raises a ValueError
image.T / x  # works
```